# cronjob mysql backup issue

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I am running this via cron:

```
30 2,8,14,20 * * * DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M`; mysqldump -u mysql_user -ppassword mysql_database | gzip > /home/username/backups/mysql_backup-$DATE.sql.gz
```

When I do it command line, it works. But the cronjob gives me an error like this:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just guessing here: `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M` shouldn't you use single quotes instead of backticks?

Comment: Hmm, nope :( I tried single quotes and it gave me `/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''` almost the same error except with single quotes.

Comment: try this: `mysqldump -u mysql_user -ppassword mysql_database | gzip > /home/username/backups/mysql_backup-\`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M\`.sql.gz`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to escape `%` by `\`. It will be:

```
30 2,8,14,20 * * *  /bin/bash -c 'DATE=$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M); echo $DATE'
```